# comparing two equations and obtaining some results

Tags: summation

Assuming the following equation
$$
\sum_{m=0}^M b_m r^m \left[\sum_{i,j}i j\lambda_i \lambda_j r^{i+j-2}-\sum_j j(j+1) \lambda_j r^{j-2}+2E\right]-2\sum_{k=0}^K a_k r^k=0 \tag{1}
$$
the authors in a paper says that

> Equating the coefficients of $r^p, p=0, 1, 2, . . .$ in (1) to zero,
>   we get a set of relations connecting $\lambda_n$s. For example, in a
>   case where M=1 and K=3, these are:

$$
\lambda_1=Z; \\
\lambda_2=(2E+\lambda^2_1)/6; \\
\lambda_3=(2\lambda_1 \lambda_2-\alpha)/6;\\
\lambda_4=(4\lambda_2^2+6\lambda_1 \lambda_3-2\beta)/20;\\
\lambda_n=\frac 1 {n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i (n-i)\lambda_i \lambda_{n-1}, n>4;\\
\tag{2}
$$
In fact they have obtained an expression for this special potential in the previous section as follows (before they write $\Psi$ as a sum, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425542/differentiating-summations))
$$
n(n-1)\mu_{n-1}+2Z\mu_n+2E\mu_{n+1}-2\alpha\mu_{n+2}-2\beta\mu_{n+3}=0 \tag{3}
$$
where 
$$
\mu_j=\int_0^\infty r^j \Psi(r)dr \tag{4}
$$
this is while after writing $\Psi$ as a sum they define 
$$
\int_0^\infty r^p exp[-S(r)]dr=\mu_p,  \,\,  p=0,1,2,...,N \tag{5}
$$

---

I can't understand how they have reached equation (2) by comparison equations (1) and (3)? or  if they have reached it in another way! Any idea?

**You can find more details in [the original paper](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/ref.pdf). Of course I have cropped the relevant parts. In this question I want to know how authors have reached from equation (11) to (12) in the paper**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with the  representation given in the *[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425542/differentiating-summations/3428346#3428346)* of the referred post which corresponds to (1).

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^M b_m r^m\left[\color{blue}{\sum_{n=2}^{2N}}\sum_{{i+j=n}\atop{i,j\geq   1}}ij\lambda_i   \lambda_jr^{i+j-2}-\sum_{j=1}^Nj(j+1)\lambda_jr^{j-2}+2E\right]
-2\sum_{k=0}^K a_k r^k=0\tag{1a}
\end{align*}

*Note:* The blue marked sum is not given in formula (11) of the original paper, which seems to be a typo.

The relations (2) stated by OP are derived in the referred paper by specialisation of (1a) to the so-called *spherical Stark–Zeeman hydrogenic problem* . We consider in the referred paper formula (6):
\begin{align*}
V(r)=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^Ka_kr^k}{\sum_{m=0}^Mb_mr^m}=\frac{-Z+\alpha r^2+\beta r^3}{r}\tag{2a}
\end{align*}

Combining (1a) and (2a) we obtain
\begin{align*}
&r\left[\sum_{n=2}^{2N}\sum_{{i+j=n}\atop{i,j\geq   1}}ij\lambda_i   \lambda_jr^{i+j-2}-\sum_{j=1}^Nj(j+1)\lambda_jr^{j-2}+2E\right]
-2\left(-Z+\alpha r^2+\beta r^3\right)=0\tag{3a}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (3a)
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{2\left(-Z-Er+\alpha r^2+\beta r^3\right)}\tag{4a}\\
> &\qquad=\sum_{n=2}^{2N}\sum_{{i+j=n}\atop{i,j\geq   1}}ij\lambda_i   \lambda_jr^{n-1}-\sum_{j=1}^Nj(j+1)\lambda_jr^{j-1}\\
> &\qquad=\sum_{n=2}^{2N}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j(n-j)\lambda_j\lambda_{n-j}r^{n-1}-\sum_{j=1}^Nj(j+1)\lambda_jr^{j-1}\tag{5a}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^{2N-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n}j(n+1-j)\lambda_j\lambda_{n+1-j}r^{n}-\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}(j+1)(j+2)\lambda_{j+1}r^{j}}\tag{6a}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5a) we eliminate $i$ using $i=n-j$.
- In (6a) we shift the indices $n$ and $j$ to ease coefficient comparison of $r^p, p\geq 0$.

> Coefficient  comparison of (4a) and (6a) gives:
>
> \begin{align*}
> -2Z&=-1\cdot2\lambda_1\tag{$[r^0]$}\\
> \color{blue}{Z}&\color{blue}{=\lambda_1}\\
> \\
> -2E&=\sum_{j=1}^1j(2-j)\lambda_j\lambda_{2-j}-2\cdot3\lambda_2\tag{$[r^1]$}\\
> -2E&=\lambda_1^2-6\lambda_2\\
> \color{blue}{\lambda_2}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{6}\left(2E+\lambda_1^2\right)}\\
> \\
> 2\alpha&=\sum_{j=1}^2j(3-j)\lambda_j\lambda_{3-j}-3\cdot 4\lambda_3\tag{$[r^2]$}\\
> 2\alpha&=2\lambda_1\lambda_2+2\lambda_2\lambda_1-12\lambda_3\\
> 2\alpha&=4\lambda_1\lambda_2-12\lambda_3\\
> \color{blue}{\lambda_3}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{6}\left(2\lambda_1\lambda_2-\alpha\right)}
> \end{align*}
> The  other relations  follow  similarly.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're a master in every sense.

Comment: @Wisdom: You're welcome. Many thanks for your nice comment.